# ActionFunction not working properly.Values not getting passed to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, actionfunction

I am facing this issue where `PassValues()` function is action function and i am passing some parameters to controller through actionfunction.I dont know whats going wrong the code is not flowing into the method..Even the debug system is not getting printed in logs..

I even saw many similar posts on this forum but didnot find any help..

The controller has many methods but for this vf page pls refer `Save method` only which is being called through `action="{!Save}"` ..

```
    <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="PolicyHolderDetails">
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetValues(){
var Name=document.getElementById('input-id1').value;
var Phone=document.getElementById('input-id2').value;
var website=document.getElementById('input-id3').value;
var street=document.getElementById('input-id4').value;
var city=document.getElementById('input-id5').value;
var state=document.getElementById('input-id6').value;
var zipcode=document.getElementById('input-id7').value;
var fax=document.getElementById('input-id8').value;
var industry=document.getElementById('input-id9').value;
if(Name=='')
{
//alert('error');
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Please Enter Policy Holder Name';
return false;
}
if(Name!=''){
alert(Name);
 PassValues(Name,Phone,website,street,city,state,zipcode,fax,industry);
alert('Details submitted successfully'); 
}                  
}
</script>
  <apex:slds />
  <apex:form >
 <center> <h1 style="font-size: 20px;">Fill out our form and get benefits..</h1></center>
 <div class="slds-form-element slds-text-title_caps" >
  <label class="slds-form-element__label " for="input-unique-id1">Policy Holder Name</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control is-required slds-has-error" id="div1" style="width: 350px;">
    <input type="text" id="input-id1" class="slds-input" required=""/><br/><br/>
  </div>
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-unique-id2">Phone</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control" style="width: 200px;">
    <input type="Number" id="input-id2" class="slds-input" /><br/><br/>
  </div>
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-unique-id3">Website</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control" style="width: 350px;">
    <input type="text" id="input-id3" class="slds-input" /><br/><br/>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
      <legend class="slds-form-element__label ">Address</legend>
      <div class="slds-form-element__group">
        <div class="slds-form-element__row">
          <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-1" style="width: 350px;">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-04">Street</label>
            <input type="text" id="input-id4" class="slds-input"/><br/><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-form-element__row">
          <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2" style="width: 350px;">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-05">City</label>
            <input type="text" id="input-id5" class="slds-input"/>
          <!--</div>-->
         <!-- <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2" style="width: 350px;">-->
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-06">State</label>
            <input type="text" id="input-id6" class="slds-input"/><br/><br/>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="slds-form-element__row">
          <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2" style="width: 300px;">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-07">ZIP Code</label>
            <input type="number" id="input-id7" class="slds-input"/><br/><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-unique-id8">Fax</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control" style="width: 350px;">
    <input type="Number" id="input-id8" class="slds-input"/><br/><br/>
  </div>
   <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-unique-id9">Industry</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control" style="width: 350px;">
    <input type="text" id="input-id9" class="slds-input" /><br/><br/>
  </div>
  </div>
 <center> <button Class="slds-button slds-button_destructive" id="btn" Onclick="GetValues()">Submit</button></center>
 <apex:actionFunction name="PassValues" action="{!Save}">
 <apex:param name="P1" value=""/>
 <apex:param name="P2" value=""/>
 <apex:param name="P3" value=""/>
 <apex:param name="P4" value=""/>
 <apex:param name="P5" value=""/>
 <apex:param name="P6" value=""/>
 <apex:param name="P7" value=""/>
 <apex:param name="P8" value=""/>
 <apex:param name="P9" value=""/>

</apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
//controller    
Public class PolicyHolderDetails {
    Public string Name{get;set;}
    Public String PhoneNo{get;set;}
    Public string Website{get;set;}
    Public string Street{get;set;}
    Public string City{get;set;}
    Public string State{get;set;}
    Public String Zipcode{get;set;}
    Public string Fax{get;set;}

    Public String Industry{get;set;}
    Public String Insurance1{get;set;}
    Public String Insurance2{get;set;}
    Public String Insurance3{get;set;}
    Public String Insurance4{get;set;}

    Public String Nominee{get;set;}
    Public String PaymentMode{get;set;}
    Public String PaymentOptions{get;set;}
    Public String PolicyCoverage{get;set;}
    Public Date EnrollmentDate{get;set;}
    Public String Tenure{get;set;}

    Public void CheckInsurance(){
     Insurance1=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param1');
     Insurance2=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param2');
     Insurance3=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param3');
     Insurance4=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param4');
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'HELLO');
     if(Insurance1=='Health Insurance'){
       system.debug('HIHIH:::::::'+Insurance1);
     system.debug(Insurance1);
       policy__c Pid=[select id from policy__c where Policy_Name__c='Health Insurance'][0];
        Account a=[Select id from Account where name=:Name][0];

      }
      if(Insurance2=='Home Insurance'){
       system.debug('HIHIH:::::::'+Insurance1);
     system.debug(Insurance1);
       policy__c Pid=[select id from policy__c where Policy_Name__c='Health Insurance'][0];
        Account a=[Select id from Account where name=:Name][0];

      }
      if(Insurance3=='Life Insurance'){
       system.debug('HIHIH:::::::'+Insurance1);
     system.debug(Insurance1);
       policy__c Pid=[select id from policy__c where Policy_Name__c='Health Insurance'][0];
        Account a=[Select id from Account where name=:Name][0];

      }
      if(Insurance4=='Automobile Insurance'){
       system.debug('HIHIH:::::::'+Insurance1);
     system.debug(Insurance1);
       policy__c Pid=[select id from policy__c where Policy_Name__c='Health Insurance'][0];
        Account a=[Select id from Account where name=:Name][0];

      }
    }

    Public PageReference Save(){ 
    system.debug('hihi:::'); 
    Name=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P1');
    PhoneNo=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P2');
    Website=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P3');
    Street=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P4');
    City=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P5');
    State=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P6');
    Zipcode=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P7');
    Fax=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P8');
    Industry=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('P9');
    Account a=new Account(name=Name,Phone=PhoneNo,Website=Website,BillingStreet=Street,BillingCity=City,
     BillingState=State,Fax=Fax,Industry=Industry,BillingPostalCode=Zipcode);
     system.debug(a);
    insert a;
     system.debug(a);
    return null;
    }

    Public PageReference SaveAgreement() {
    system.debug('HHIIH:::');
      Agreement__c ag=new Agreement__c(Policy__c='a007F0000033ROm',Policy_Holder__c='0017F000007Ndrv',Nominee__c=Nominee,Payment_mode__c=PaymentMode,
      Payment_Options__c=PaymentOptions,Policy_Coverage__c=PolicyCoverage,
        Enrollment_Date__c=EnrollmentDate,Tenure__c=Tenure);
       insert ag; 
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/134406

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add rerender attribute in your actionFunction, like this `rerender='none'`. It is a known issue in Salesforce that if you are not using rerender, then your actionFunction may not work properly.

Comment: Atlast thank you very much Aashish and sfdcfox..It helped..But why we need to proivde rerender??

Comment: it is a known salesforce bug. actionSupport and actionFunction, both acts weirdly when rerender is not used with them. Not your fault at all. :)

Comment: Ok!!Thanks very much!!But salesforce has to fix this i wasted almost 2 days on this issue.